# Feature extraction using Keras does not include class labels

Tags: machine-learning, keras, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

I use Keras for applying image classification on MNIST dataset, implementation is available [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py). I use this implementation but with adding the following method to extract features from trained images:

```
def feature_extraction(model, x_test, path_to_save):
    extract = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer('dense_1').output)
    features = extract.predict(x_test)
    np.savetxt(path_to_save, features, delimiter=",")
```

The output file does not contain class labels, i.e., each row in the file is a set of features but without a class label. Is there a way to modify this method so that it also adds the class label of each extracted feature (i.e. each row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get multiple outputs, so both the features and the predicted label probabilities:

```
extract = Model(model.input, [model.get_layer('dense_1').output, model.output])
features, labels = extract.predict(x_test)
labels = np.argmax(labels, axis=1)
```

The prediction will now give you both output. You might want to `np.argmax` to get the actual class label rather than the probabilities depending on the model.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I use `np.argmax`? Kindly can you show that in the example as well?

Comment: I am sorry but do you know why I am getting `features, labels = extract.predict(x_test)  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`? It seems `predict` does not output labels

Comment: Care to debug? Maybe print it, check what it returns, how many values it returns, I haven't looked at the model so I'm not sure.